# Как составить запрос в Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel, laravel5, eloquent

Есть запрос sql который нужно составить в Laravel:

```
select * from orders where status is not null
and ((partner_id = 13) or (owner_id = 13))
and created_at between '2019-06-10 00:00:54' and '2019-06-10 20:27:54'
```

я делаю вот так :

```
$orders = Order::whereNotNull('status')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('partner_id', $user->id);})
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user) {
                    $query->where('owner_id', $user->id);})
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereBetween('created_at', array('2019-06-10 00:00:00', '2019-06-10 23:11:21'));});
```

но мне из такого запроса выдает вот такой sql:

```
select * from `orders` where 
(`status` is not null and (`partner_id` = 13) or (`owner_id` = 13)
and (`created_at` between '2019-06-10 00:00:00' and '2019-06-10 23:11:21')) 
and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null
```

как мне вынести за скобки вот эту строку:

```
and (`created_at` between '2019-06-10 00:00:00' and '2019-06-10 23:11:21')
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю правильно или нет но я сделал вот так и это мне помогло:

```
$orders = Order::whereRaw("make_status is not null and ((partner_id = ". $user->id .") or (owner_id = ". $user->id ."))")->whereBetween('created_at', ['2019-06-10 00:00:00', '2019-06-10 23:11:21'])
```